# Can In App Purchases be tested in the IOS 8 (Xcode 6) Simulator?

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

I keep finding conflicting information about whether In App Purchases can actually be tested on a simulator using Xcode 6. Some answers say '*yes*', others seem to indicate there are a bug in beta versions of Xcode 6 and others flat out '*no*'.

I have an app where IAP works great on the device, but in the simulator, trying to refresh the receipt fails with a very unhelpful message: `Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 0.)"`.

My app was rejected from the app store because the tester could not test (even though it works perfectly with sandbox accounts on devices) and I am beginning to suspect that they simply tested on a simulator and were not able to proceed.
Since I had read so much about it not working on a simulator and that you had to test on a device, I didn't worry about it not working on the simulator but that may have bitten me in the backside.

Can anyone say that they have actually gotten IAP to work on IOS 8 / Xcode 6 simulators?

Answer (score 13):

Most of the StoreKit sandbox does mysteriously now seem to work when using a debug-build iOS 8 target in the Xcode 6 simulator.

You can't buy an auto-renewing subscription though. You get as far as the final confirmation dialog but after that the transaction always comes back with a `transactionState` of `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`. Same code works on the device. I reported this on Radar, but Apple replied that StoreKit is not supported in the simulator, which is weird given that it does all seem very close to working.

Comment: I am indeed testing auto renew subscriptions, however I can not even fetch the receipts on the Simulator. On the simulator, it never prompts for an apple id/password, it just fails right away with "The operation couldn’t be completed." - so I never even get to transactions. How long ago was it that Apple told you that StoreKit is not supported on a simulator?

Comment: A couple of weeks ago I got an Apple RADAR comment saying that in-app purchase is not supported in the Simulator, although that was in response to a slightly different bug. Now I check though, I see that my main bug about this stuff got resolved as a duplicate and the bug it's a duplicate of is still open. Maybe there is hope that this is supposed to work and Apple will fix it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in any simulator (Xcode 6.3.2). Restore connects but gets no reply. Buy puts up the dialogs but fails with Error "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Answer (score 4):

Actually, i have been tested in-app purchase in xcode 6 / iOS 8 simulator and it just work perfect (sandbox purchase and restore). 
However the other simulators (iOS 7.0.3 and 7.1) was not work for IAP.

So, the answer is **yes**.

Does your app contain verification methods for IAP receipt ? May be it is seemed too simple but are you sure that the verifications control **not** with https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Comment: I am indeed verifying the receipt locally. However, I am using StoreKit's SKReceiptRefreshRequest which does not expose any endpoint URLs. A tcpdump capture shows that it is talking to the sandbox server, which is what we want for development. Why is it you say that the verifications should NOT be done with the sandbox? This works perfectly on a device.

Comment: Because, the Apple review team testing IAP with this adress: https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt . You can check details from this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)
But you said that verified the receipt locally. So now, it does not matter where you verify..

Comment: that's actually not true, Apple's team tests with Sandbox accounts and NOT production accounts, thus the application must work with both Sandbox and Production users. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-FREQUENTLY_ASKED_QUESTIONS #15 and #16.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. i always switch to production server while apple review. And i have never face to problem. When i look this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/AppReview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH10-SW1) at the figure 7.1, i think that i should use production server.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, according to Apple Tech Support, IAP have not been fully supported in the Simulator since XCode 5, and they indicate there is no status change on this, thus one can only assume that IAP is still not 100% supported on the Simulator.

Comment: As of 2015-04-20, I am unable to get IAP to work in the Xcode 6.3 simulator. Code works on the device, but the simulator always returns SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Comment: @ThomasZimmer Did you happen to find out why this is the case? Or any other useful information? Thanks.